# git cloned files in windows are not visible in explorer. neither are the folders created in cygwin

Tags: git, windows-7, cygwin, explorer

I'm not able to view files in explorer that are cloned using git..

see the following image for more detail.. also this is driving me crazy..

[image]

Comment: It works for me. I just repeated your commands in `cmd.exe` and it does what I expect, not what you show. Is your `git` a Cygwin version, or a native port? Have you checked for (and disabled) [BLODA](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.using.html#faq.using.bloda)?

Answer (score 0):

`ls` doesn't show hidden files and folders by default.
try `ls -al`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/SotSO.png okay i see them now... but how to change directory into it.. if they are hidden i should be able to see in explorer, after enabling the option of seeing hidden files?

Comment: i dont see them in explorer.. do you find anything peculiar in the image i posted above? how to cd into hidden folder?

Comment: cd .git should work. A;so the image you posted above doesn't show the git folders. Do a cd vim-fugitive then ls -al

Comment: wait so the folders test and vim-fugitive are not hidden? im not able to cd into them..

Comment: im not able to do cd into test or vim-fugitive(inn command prompt).. im able to cd in bash